# Can not change directory to the .ssh folder using command line

Tags: laravel, command-line, ssh, directory, command

Basically, I want to change to the .ssh folder.
So I typed

```
MikesdeMacBook-Pro:~ Mike$ cd .ssh
```

And here is the result:

```
-bash: cd: .ssh: Not a directory
```

This is what I typed to try to find the folder:

```
MikesdeMacBook-Pro:~ Mike$ ls -ls .ssh
8 -rw-------  1 Mike  staff  1675 Jun 19 00:53 .ssh
```

I am not sure whether there is a problem. I have created the ssh keygen but it still shows "Not a directory".

Comment: .ssh is a file. Directories start with a "d" in the second field of ls -ls. Try deleting the .ssh file and rerunning keygen.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the keygen was not run correctly or there was already a `.ssh` file on your computer. As in my comment try deleting the `.ssh` file and rerunning `ssh-keygen`.